# How accessing objects multiple time work in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to understand how spring security works and I confront the HttpSecurity object, hope someone can answer my questions.

- How can I set the values sequentially like this?
- Is it coming as `null` first and I set the configuration values from the start? or it has default values and I complete it?
- How it sets the values in multi-calls without overwriting the previous values? what is this approach name in Java? Can I do the same with my objects?
- Is there a way that I can see what are its current values?

```java
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    log.info("1: {}", http.toString());
            
    http.csrf().disable().httpBasic();
    http.authorizeRequests().mvcMatchers("api/**").authenticated();
    http.headers() // X-Content-Type-Options
        .frameOptions().disable() // x-frame-options
        .httpStrictTransportSecurity()// Strict-Transport-Security
        .contentTypeOptions();
    log.info("2: {}", http.toString());
            
    http.addFilterBefore(filterChainExceptionHandler, LogoutFilter.class);
    log.info("3: {}", http.toString());

    return http.build();
}
```

**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: I don't understand the questions but in any case SO is not really there to explain concepts but rather correct mistakes in code... Try reading a book/documentation perhaps?

Comment: Welcome to stakoverflow. I suggest to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your post has many questions. You should ask one per post. Also the idea of the platform is to help to fix a specific problem that you have when you try to do something.

Comment: If you don't already know about it, perhaps have a look at the so called _builder pattern_: [Exploring Joshua Bloch’s Builder design pattern in Java](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/exploring-joshua-blochs-builder-design-pattern-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I set the values sequentially like this?

`HttpSecurity` internally has a list of  `SecurityConfigurer` to configure different parts of `HttpSecurity`.  You can think that the methods on it such as `csrf()` , `headers()` or `authorizeRequests()` etc. just return one of these `SecurityConfigurer` for you to configure. It allows to configure the value sequentially just because it implements the [method chaining](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/method-chaining-in-java-with-examples/) by returning 'this' instance.

> Is it coming as null first and I set the configuration values from the
> start? or it has default values and I complete it?

`HttpSecurity` is a bean that is defined by in [`HttpSecurityConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/7e0fcb7daeb19543e90aa0375308b4bd67f70b94/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/HttpSecurityConfiguration.java#L105C48-L105C48) . Spring Boot will somehow enable it through `@EnableWebSecurity`. Now if you look its source codes , it defines the `HttpSecurity` bean as the followings :

```java
HttpSecurity httpSecurity() throws Exception {
        WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.LazyPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.LazyPasswordEncoder(
                this.context);
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationBuilder = new WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.DefaultPasswordEncoderAuthenticationManagerBuilder(
                this.objectPostProcessor, passwordEncoder);
        authenticationBuilder.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        authenticationBuilder.authenticationEventPublisher(getAuthenticationEventPublisher());
        HttpSecurity http = new HttpSecurity(this.objectPostProcessor, authenticationBuilder, createSharedObjects());
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .csrf(withDefaults())
            .addFilter(new WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter())
            .exceptionHandling(withDefaults())
            .headers(withDefaults())
            .sessionManagement(withDefaults())
            .securityContext(withDefaults())
            .requestCache(withDefaults())
            .anonymous(withDefaults())
            .servletApi(withDefaults())
            .apply(new DefaultLoginPageConfigurer<>());
        http.logout(withDefaults());
        // @formatter:on
        applyDefaultConfigurers(http);
        return http;
    }
```

So it has already defined some default value. You then define the `filterChain` bean to override some of the default value based on your application security requirement.

> How it sets the values in multi-calls without overwriting the previous
> values? what is this approach name in Java? Can I do the same with my
> objects?

It depends on the implementation of that method. Some method will overwrite the previous value such as `http.csrf().disable()` while some method will add one more configuration to the related `SecurityConfigurer` such as `http.authorizeRequests().mvcMatchers("api/**").authenticated()`.

This approach is use method chaining to build a [DSL-like API](https://illegalexception.schlichtherle.de/patterns/2013/06/06/on-domain-specific-languages-in-java-part-1-method-chaining/) for configuring the `HttpSecurity`.

> Is there a way that I can see what are its current values?

As `HttpSecurity` is a bean , that means you can define a spring bean and inject it into this bean such that you can navigate and access its internal structure to see its current value.

For example, implement a `CommandLineRunner` which will execute at the application startup is a nice way to go :

```java
@Component
public class MyCommandLineRunner implement CommandLineRunner {
    
    @Autowired
    private HttpSecurity httpSecurity;

    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        //access httpSecurity to see if current value.
    }

}
```